# 3 wires unipolar system existance

Tags: stepper-motor

I have one stepper motor, it's a permanent magnet.
Does the 3 wires unipolar exist? can a 3 wires unipolar system be created from the 4 wires bipolar
I didn't find any structures of it.
Ines

Comment: I've never heard of a 3 wire stepper motor, all the ones I've used had 4 wires.

Answer (score 0):

3-wire unipolar steppers don't exist. The standard is 5 or 6.

In principle you could make a 3-wire bipolar motor, with the two windings in series, but the driver would be unpleasantly complex, and the performance of the motor would suffer, as the maximum voltage available to each winding would be reduced for a given controller power supply, and this would reduce maximum speed.